# Django Rest Framework - Marking extra actions for routing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the next view on my API

```
class CapsuleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Capsule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CapsuleSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    @action(detail=True)
    def modules(self, request, pk=None):

        capsule = self.get_object()
        capsule_modules = Module.objects.filter(capsule=capsule)
        serializer = ModuleSerializer(capsule_modules, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When i try to get all the modules related to a capsule, the URL of the imageField of a module is incomplete.

When i call http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/capsules/1/ it returns:

```
{
    "capsuleID": 1,
    "capsuleName": "sdfads",
    "capusuleDetails": "asdf",
    "capsuleImageURL": "http://0.0.0.0:8000/media/capsulas/logocitbm.png",
    "userStars": 0,
    "pallete": {
        "palleteID": 1,
        "palleteName": "Default smartraining",
        "colors": [
            {
                "colorID": 1,
                "colorName": "A1",
                "colorCode": "#sdfs"
            },
            {
                "colorID": 2,
                "colorName": "A2",
                "colorCode": "#dsfksdoif"
            },
            {
                "colorID": 3,
                "colorName": "A3",
                "colorCode": "#sdjfjgioj"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but when i call http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/capsules/1/modules/ i get:

```
[
    {
        "moduleID": 1,
        "moduleName": "sdfa",
        "moduleDetails": "así",
        "moduleImageURL": "/media/modulos/9_-_4._Detalle_C%C3%A1psula.png",
        "userScore": 0
    }
]
```

the moduleImageURL is incomplete, why?
these are my serializers:

```
class CapsuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    pallete = PalleteSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Capsule
        fields = ('capsuleID', 'capsuleName', 'capusuleDetails', 'capsuleImageURL', 'userStars', 'pallete')

class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = ('moduleID', 'moduleName', 'moduleDetails', 'moduleImageURL', 'userScore')
```

Answer (score 3):

After some research i find that i need pass the context to the ModelSerializer like this:

```
serializer = ModuleSerializer(capsule_modules, many=True, context={'request': request})
```

Comment: Note: this is also a good case to use nested routing. https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers